# User settings disappear on outlook upgrades

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, outlook-2007

i'm developing an outlook plug in where users set a list of settings like credentials and site url...
I'am saving this settings in settings.settings in my windows application project.

after installing the add in the config file is set under C:\Users\ ***user*** \AppData\Local\Microsoft_Corporation\ ***project name*** \ *** < outlook Version> *** \user.config.

My problem is when performing update for the microsoft office outlook the ***outlook version*** changed so my add in will not be able to find the user settings.

How can i pass this problem???
Is it the best practice to save the user settings in settings.settings file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I ran into a similar problem a while back, I found this page helpful: http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/33944/0/page/4.

It basically requires calling:

```
<your assembly>.Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade();
```

Answer (score 2):

I remember that there is a My.Settings.Upgrade method, which transfers settings between assembly updates. I'd rather use an own settings class and a path about which I decide.
You can also decide to write your own upgrade routine in the case of an major application update.